# How do I make a button to add new fields in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, copy-paste, visual-basic

I have a formula which uses a constant.  Every time I copy and paste the cells for a new day, I want the constant to update to the new one.

I was thinking I could create a button to copy the fields and update the constant so that the person editing the document every time wouldn't have to do the copy, paste, change constant... each time.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm creating a tip calculator.  The calculator takes the number of hours worked per employee, and calculates the total tips per hour worked from the total tips (which is the constant).  We then take that constant and multiple times the hours worked per employee.

For example, 100$ tips, 3 employees, 8 hrs = x, 10 hrs = y, 4 hrs = z
total number hrs, 22
tips per hr = 4.55
4.55x, 4.55y, 4.55z, will give you the total tips per employee.

Now each day we click the button to add a new set of fields with all employees, hours, a place for the tips, etc...  i can't think of where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would convert the existing data range into a Table. You can achieve this by selecting all the Rows and Columns, then going to the Insert ribbon and choosing Table.

Once you have a Table, then any formula you enter for a row is automatically copied to all the other rows for that column. This also extends as you add new rows - you can just start typing in the row below the last row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a macro to record the steps of copy, paste, then clear cells. Then you can assign it to an object; in your case a button. Here are some instructions to get you started.

[Create or delete a macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-macro-HP010014111.aspx)